# Extract data for several user ids in SEDE

Tags: support, data-explorer, data-dump

How do I extract data from data.stackexchange.com for several user ids?
I'm trying to do

```sql
select * from posts where (owneruserid = 123 or owneruserid = 456);
```

but it only outputs the results for the user with id 123.
I need it because I noticed that a user has different ids on different Stack Exchange communities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query works, but it only queries one database (the one in the URL, after `data.stackexchange.com/`), and the data of different communities is stored in different databases.

There are some options to do cross-site queries, by explicitly specifying the database:

```
SELECT * FROM [StackOverflow].dbo.Posts WHERE OwnerUserId = 15915007
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM [SuperUser].dbo.Posts WHERE OwnerUserId = 1399513
```

[The query above](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1509469) gives all your posts on Stack Overflow and Super User. It's even better to `JOIN` with the `Users` table and filter on `AccountId`, which you can find in the [URL of your network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current).

If you're really into advanced SQL stuff, you can query `sys.databases` to check which databases are available in SEDE, generate a dynamic SQL to query all those databases at once (or only a subset, like all Metas) and execute that query. [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/740847/networkwide-questions-per-account-ordered-by-view-count) is an example, though there are many others which may be easier to understand.